# Twillio Audio Conferencing

Tags: twilio, webrtc, audio-streaming

I'm planning to use Twillio audio conference example (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/conference-broadcast) to build a live audio streaming application. But is it true that Twillio always require a phone number to facilitate this? Other PaaS providers such as Argora abstract this with something like a Channel and it seems to me a better abstraction. Can I get something like a Channel from Twillio?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/video - this is probably the abstraction you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah. That is the abstraction. However, I do not need video and am looking for Voice API and it requires a phone number.

Comment: that api does not mandate video.

Comment: Are you broadcasting by calling participants via the PSTN (phone network)? What is the use case?